# Error setting UIPickerView as input for UITextField in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to swift programming and I want to set a **UIPickerView** as input for a **UITextField**. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var  selectTransportCompany: UITextField!
    var data = ["DHL Express", "Fed Ex", "TNT", "Express Mail"]
    var picker = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        selectTransportCompany.inputView = picker
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return data.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectTransportCompany.text = data[row]

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[row]
    }


}
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error saying

> Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Going into the debugger, I get this:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can anybody know what the issue is, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgHEL1bWQ58) too.

Comment: You just have to connect your view controller text field outlet to your storyboard selectTransportCompany textField.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87285547/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-19%20at%2004.32.00.png

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Can you update this as an answer, if so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to connect your view controller text field outlet to your storyboard selectTransportCompany textField.

[image]